# Android Bar code Scanning issue

Tags: android

I am Working on bar code scanning using [Zxing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing), I found lot of related links on stack overflow , but some of my devices are unable scan .

Is auto focus of device is mandatory to scan ?

If not please provide suggestion for scanning.

Comment: did you set aspect ratio .??

Comment: No. may i know Is auto focus of device is mandatory to scan? if not please provide solution for scan.

Comment: i know but there is one class that we set aspect ratio .. you need to change it. Then code work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

For android best way to do bar code scanning is to use google play service sppport library for Barcode API .
[here](https://developers.google.com/vision/barcodes-overview) is link for barcode api.

Demo for this library is also avilable [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader)